# joining tables with different length column values

Tags: t-sql

I need to get ID by joining columns of tables with variable length.
Table A has 2 columns ID and PostCode

```
-----------------
| ID | PostCode |
|----|----------|
| 1  |    BR    |
|----|----------|
| 2  |    WT    |
|----|----------|
| 3  |    B71   |
|----|----------|
| 4  |    BR5   |
|----|----------|
```

Table B has columns with Name and Full postcode

```
|------|----------|
| Name | PostCode |
|------|----------|
| Mr X | CR2  5ER |
|------|----------|
| Ms Y | BT2  6ER |
|------|----------|
| XX   | B71  4WQ |
|------|----------|
| YY   | BR4  8ER |
|------|----------|
| SS   | BR5A 5RT |
|------|----------|
```

I need to get Id's 1 [BR->BR4 8ER], 3 [B71->B71 4WQ] and 4 [BR5->BR5A 5RT]
How do I get to work this?

Comment: So you want to join on the string `PostCode`, `TableB` must contain this (sub-)string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help.

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE (UserID INT,
                   PostCode VARCHAR(10))
DECLARE @TableB TABLE (Name VARCHAR(10),
                   PostCode VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @TableA
VALUES
('1', 'BR'),
('2', 'WT'),
('3', 'B71'),
('4', 'BR5')

INSERT INTO @TableB
VALUES
('Mr X', 'CR2  5ER'),
('Ms Y', 'BT2  6ER'),
('XX', 'B71  4WQ'),
('YY', 'BR4  8ER'),
('SS', 'BR5A 5RT');
WITH CTE
    AS (
    SELECT CAST(UserID AS VARCHAR(10)) AS UserID,
         Name,
         tb.PostCode,
         ta.PostCode AS PostCode2
         ,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY tb.PostCode DESC) AS PcID
    FROM @TableA AS ta
        JOIN @TableB AS tb
        ON ta.PostCode = LEFT(tb.PostCode, LEN(ta.PostCode))
    )
, cte2
    AS (
    SELECT STUFF((SELECT ', ' + c2.UserID + ' [' + c2.PostCode2 + '-' + c2.PostCode + ']'
               FROM cte AS c2
               WHERE c1.UserID = c2.UserID
                AND PcID = 1
               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS PostCodeMatch
    FROM cte AS c1
    WHERE PcID = 1
    )
    SELECT DISTINCT STUFF((SELECT ', ' + PostCodeMatch
                      FROM cte2 AS c2
                      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS PostCodeMatch
    FROM cte2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry for confusion but match I had specified was to give a idea for record matching not the result set. However, the logic has helped me in getting the correct join match.

Comment: @user2614735 I am glad it was of help. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select A.PostCode, B.PostCode as FullPostCode, B.Name
  from A
  join B 
    on substring(B.PostCode,0,len(A.PostCode)) =  A.PostCode
```

Comment: This will match BR and BR5 both.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the postcode BR29 8LN. If table A has codes B and BR, this postcode will be captured TWICE - not what the OP would want, and not what I wanted.

The below captures everything so long as after the postcode prefix, there is a number thus delimiting the postcode area:

```
  select A.PostCode, B.PostCode as FullPostCode, B.Name
  from B
  inner join A 
    on substring(B.PostCode ,0,len(A.PostCode)+1) = A.PostCode
    WHERE IsNumeric(substring(B.PostCode ,len(A.PostCode)+1,1)) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You might do something like this:

```
select A.PostCode, B.PostCode as FullPostCode, B.Name
from A
join B on B.PostCode like A.PostCode + '%'
```

Comment: This will return multiple matches, not the best match.