# SQL How to join multiple tables on a variable length value

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to associate values from three Tables efficiently.
There are several million records in Calls and thousands of records in Area.
The problem I am having is that the values I like to join on are of different length

Calls.CalledNumber is joined on the best matching Area.AreaCode

Calls.CalledNumber is joined on the best matching Country.CountryCode

Can anybody help me with this?

Desired output:

```
CalledNumber    Country     Area
+61732596265    Australia
+61418130662    Australia   Mobile
6324
7085
+6474506817     New Zealand
+6494313817     New Zealand Warkworth
+1800485614     USA         Toll Free
+41449036311    Switzerland
+6494310655     New Zealand Maungaturoto
+642108475634   New Zealand Vodafone
```

The Tables I would like to join:

Table Calls

```
CalledNumber
+61732596265
+61418130662
6324
7085
+6474506817
+64701506817
+1800485614
+41449036311
+6442267655
+642108475634
```

Table Area

```
AreaCode    AreaName
+649425     Warkworth
+649426     Hibiscus Coast
+649427     Hibiscus Coast
+649428     Hibiscus Coast
+649429     Great Barrier Island
+649430     Whangarei
+6494310    Maungaturoto
+6494311    Maungaturoto
+6494312    Warkworth
+6494313    Warkworth
+6494314    Warkworth
+614        Mobile
+1800       Toll Free
+6421       Vodafone
```

Table Country

```
CountryCode CountryName
+61         Australia
+64         New Zealand
+1          USA
+41         Switzerland
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: refer this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25122476/joining-tables-with-different-length-column-values

Comment: You have in your desired output calls that have not been made!?!?

Comment: Why "best matching"?  Do you have codes that are a substring of another?  Eg. +6494312 Warkworth and +649431 Greater Warkworth?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Code for your Problem in MYSQL:

```
SELECT CalledNumber,IFNULL(CountryName,'') AS Country,IFNULL(AreaName,'') AS Area FROM calls cl 
LEFT join area ar on left(cl.callednumber,length(ar.areacode)) = ar.areacode
LEFT join country co on left(cl.callednumber,length(co.countrycode)) = co.countrycode
```

For MSSQL(SQL SERVER):

> Replace IFNULL() WITH ISNULL()

Also you can check below code snippet:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eaa35c/4

Comment: This it is what I was trying to do. It is still very CPU intensive and does take a long time.

Comment: Try and check by calculating length of areacode and countrycode before joining.

Comment: Have you found a better solution??

Answer (score 0):

A way could be by using LIKE operator to match the call numbers with area codes in your join:

```
SELECT
t1.callednumbers,
t2.areaname,
t3.countryname
FROM
calls t1
LEFT JOIN
area t2
ON t1.callednumbers like t2.areacode||'%' 
LEFT JOIN
country t3
ON t2.areacode like t3.countrycode||'%';
```

This works on Postgres as well.
Let me know if you are on the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Performance will probably be terrible, but this may use a bit less CPU than Nishant's solution.

```
select c.*, a.*, cy.*
    from calls c
    left join area a
         on c.callednumber like concat(a.areacode,'%')
    left join country cy
         on c.callednumber like concat(cy.countrycode,'%')
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7dcd3c/8